# Can I use Dwolla's guest checkout to simultaneously create a Dwolla account for the user?

Tags: php, checkout, dwolla

Ideally the user wouldn't have to enter all their information a 2nd time if they decide to use Dwolla again.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users are given the option to choose a password at the end of a guest checkout session, which triggers a full account creation based on the information they had already supplied. So, that should do the trick!